# Not able to call home page in Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to call index,jsp from controller on startup of tomcat. But not able to get succeed.
I am using eclipse Neon and java 1.8 and tomcat 7 in this.
Give comments where i am wrong.
Thanks in Advance.

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TrackStudent</display-name>
  <!-- <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list> -->
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TrackStudent</groupId>
  <artifactId>TrackStudent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.7.5</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.getLocation.controller" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <!-- <mvc:resources mapping="/resource/**" location="/resource/" /> -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/view/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
    package com.getLocation.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public ModelAndView defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("In defaultMethod");
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

}
```

Comment: suppose you have index.jsp inside your view folder.  try with this 
 `@RequestMapping(value = { "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("In defaultMethod");
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
  model.setViewName("index");
        return model;
    }`

Comment: have you added `@RequestMapping(value ="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)`to your 'HomeController '

Comment: throw error: HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception

Comment: when i clean build the pom.xml, it is showing 404 error

Comment: think it can not locate the page now.

Answer (score 0):

To map DispatcherServlet to your welcome page "/" you need to add in xml :

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
```

And if you want java code :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` is inside your WEB-INF folder. your web.xml file must be changed like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TrackStudent</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.getLocation.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index**", "/index/**" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("In defaultMethod");
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
}
```

Comment: getting : HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception:
error

Comment: @balvindersingh modified the answer.

Comment: same error retains, in tomcat it is --Apr 04, 2017 11:44:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:

Comment: and after maven clean build it is showing 404 error :(

Comment: @balvindersingh can you share the whole stack trace or exception. It may be helpful to find the root cause